# Area of a triangle inside a square

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a square and $S_{ABCD}=2016$. $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $O=AC\cap BD,$ $N=BD \cap CM$ and $P=AC\cap DM.$ Find the area of $MNOP$.

[image]

So we can write the area of $MNOP$ as $$S_{MNOP}=S_{\triangle AOB}-S_{\triangle AMP}-S_{\triangle BMN}$$
The first area is equal to $$S_{\triangle AOB}=\dfrac14S_{\triangle ABCD}=504$$
I can't find the areas of $S_{\triangle AMP}$ and $S_{\triangle BMN}$. Any other ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: $P$ is centroid of $\triangle ABD$

Comment: So altitude from $P$ to $AM$ is $\dfrac{1}{3}$ of $AD$

Answer (score 1):

Math Lover's comment is far more elegant than my answer...

But what I've done is:

I called $a = AD$ then I set the origin of the plane at $A$. The straight line $(AC)$ has for equation:

$$y = x \quad (1)$$

And $(DM)$,

$$y = -2x+a \quad (2)$$

We know that $P$ is at the intersection of $(AC)$ and $(DM)$ hence $y_P = x_P $ and $y_P = -2x_P+a$ therefore we deduce $y_P = \frac{a}{3}$.

To conclude,

$$S_{\triangle APM} = \dfrac{1}{2} \left(\dfrac{a}{3} \times \dfrac{a}{2}\right)=\dfrac{a^2}{12} = \dfrac{2016}{12} = 168$$

Answer (score 1):

Since P is the intersection of medians of triangle ABD
$$\frac{OP}{AP}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{S(\triangle ACM)}{S(\triangle POM)}=\frac{1}{6}$$

$$\frac{S(\triangle ACM)}{S(\square ABCD)}=\frac{1}{4}$$

$${S(\triangle ACM)}=504$$

$${S(\triangle POM)}=84$$

$${S(POMN)}=168$$